# IBMBlueMix has not been initialized - when setting up the push notification service using Cordova

Tags: push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I tried to set up the push notification service in cordova mobile app. I followed all the steps described in the tutorial http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-push-apache-cordova-app/

However, I am getting the below errors

1)IBMBlueMix has not been initialized 2) Unable to access browser's navigator object

I can confirm that i used the correct appid,approute and appsecret details extracted from bluemix console

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

That sample is out of date and the cordova SDK it is using has since been deprecated.

Please take a look at [this sample for utilizing IBM Push Notifications with Cordova on Bluemix](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-cordova-hellopush).

Additionally you can find further documentation on the current Cordova SDK at the Bluemix Documentation hub for mobile: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobile.html